# SQL - How to split a string with multiple instances of the same string, separated by carriage returns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the data I have, it's separated by carriage returns.

```
'AM 1492       AM 1791       PM 1492       PM 1791       '
```

Desired results:

[image: screenshot of data on each row]

How do I get each piece of data on its own row?  I've tried CharIndex to identify the character and I was thinking of using a substring, but I'm not sure how to separate each item into a row when there are multiple instances of a string like 'AM', 'AM', etc.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    StringInfo VARCHAR (500)
)

INSERT INTO #T1 (StringInfo)
VALUES ('AM 1492       AM 1791       PM 1492       PM 1791       ')

SELECT * 
FROM #T1 AS T
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's separated by a carriage return, just a bunch of spaces.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(T.StringInfo, '       ', '|'), '|')` should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it truly is a carriage return then the following should do the job:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    StringInfo NVARCHAR (500)
)

INSERT INTO #T1 (StringInfo)
VALUES ('AM 1492
AM 1791
PM 1492
PM 1791')

SELECT value
FROM #T1 cross apply string_split(StringInfo, Char(13)) as p
```

---

```
value
AM 1492
AM 1791
PM 1492
PM 1791
```

Comment: Thanks, @JNevill!  I appreciate you taking the time to help me!  Your answer worked for me!